# Compute the mean of a series of user-entered numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

Which is more elegant out of two methods as mentioned below mostly from memory prospective?

Both methods achieve the same result, but from a memory perspective, In Method1, we are storing the running total and count separately, using two variables. while In Method2, we are using a list to store all input values and then calculate the sum and length of the list to determine the average. However, I see Method2 abstracts the details of the accumulation process by utilizing built-in functions (`sum` and `len`), which can be considered more elegant?

**Method 1:**

```
total = 0 
count = 0

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter a number: ')

    if user_input == 'done':
        break

    value = float(user_input)
    total += value
    count += 1

average = total / count
print(f'Average: {average}')
```

**Method 2:**

```
numbers = []

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter a number: ')

    if user_input == 'done':
        break

    value = float(user_input)
    numbers.append(value)

if numbers:
    average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(f'Average: {average}')
else:
    print('No numbers entered.')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're going to have a hard time applying adjectives like "elegant"
to code that intermixes computation with user input.
So let's address that first, with a generator:

```
def get_numbers():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Enter a number: ')

        if user_input == 'done':
            return

        yield float(user_input)
```

Feel free to replace this function
with `get_numbers_from_csv` or `get_numbers_from_tcp_connection`.

Ok, now that that
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
is packaged up inside a generator
we can turn to the alternative algorithms.

They do entirely different things.

In method 1 we consume O(1) constant memory,
and as a consequence cannot answer other questions
about the input (e.g. "what was the median value?").
This is a partial function over its possible inputs,
since it blows up with `ZeroDivisionError`
in the empty input case.
(There are also corner cases where user might
enter ±inf or NaN.)

In method 2 we accept the cost of allocation that is O(N) linear
with size of input.
So we're doing an entirely different thing.
And then we enjoy the flexibility of being able to conveniently compute `sum()`, `min()`,
and so on. We could even choose to sort and report a median figure.

I'm going to consider a different adjective: "fast".
Is this method fast?
Yes, once the numbers are all available,
method 2 is significantly faster than method 1.
But it's just an implementation detail of cPython,
a matter of looking at how many interpreted bytecode operations
are responsible for accomplishing the task,
contrasted with getting C code to do the same task more rapidly.

The `sum()` builtin is implemented in compiled C,
so it benchmarks quicker.
But what is that C code doing?
We made it chase N object references in the `list`,
and then go figure out if each object supports left or right addition,
and finally perform the FP operation and store it.

We *could* ask cPython to do less work.
Put each value in an
[array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)
cell using `numbers = array('d', get_numbers())`, or perhaps prefer
[numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html).
Now we no longer have N allocated object pointers to chase,
and we already *know* we're definitely talking about a FP number
rather than say, a
[Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)
or a non-numeric object like a `str`.
So the looping C code has less work to do, and it completes sooner.
If your use case allows switching from double to single-precision float
then you can get away with doing just half the work.

There's multiple adjectives you might apply to such code.
Maybe "lazy"?

Comment: .@J_h, Thanks for the great explanation .